# Access nested JSON value first element

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to figure out how to access a nested JSON attributes, first element. Basically, my data looks like the following:

```
{ 
  "message": "Error scenario",
  "errors": {
   "error_one": "error_one_message",
   "error_two": "error_two"
  }
}
```

Within my code, I am doing something like:

```
// it is an instance of HttpException
val message = JsonParser().parse(it.response().errorBody()?.string())
                           .asJsonOject["message"]
                           .asString
```

What should I change in my code to make the variable `message` have the value `error_one_message`

Answer (score 2):

I think this way will work

```
    val message = JsonParser().parse(it.response().errorBody()?.string())
                       .asJsonObject["errors"]["error_one"]
                       .asString
```

but its better to use converting library like Gson here is [GitHub Link](https://github.com/google/gson)

Answer (score 1):

Try this?

```
val obj = JSONObject("ur Json string")
val error1 = obj.getJSONObject("errors").getString("error_one")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//the whole json object
val baseJsonResponse = JSONObject("JSON response")
//the error json object
val errorObject = baseJsonResponse.getJSONObject("error")

//get the string
val location = errorObject.getString("error_one")
```

**edit:** 
since you need the first element of the base object you will need to iterate through the keys to get the 1st key. In java it would be:

```
String keyForFirstJsonbject = errorObject.keySet().iterator().next();
```

im guessing in Kotlin it will be:

```
val keyForFirstJsonbject = errorObject.keys.elementAt(0)
```

then finish off with:

```
//get the string
val location = errorObject.getString(keyForFirstJsonbject)
```

Comment: Thank's, but the catch is that the key would be different every single time. Is there any way to pick the first key by index or something. For now, as a workaround, I am doing the same steps as you described, but then get all the keys iterator and use the first key and get the value.

Comment: @GayanHewa you will need to iterate through the keys of json object and then query the first key to get the location string